# Autodesk Forge Design Automation Revit change Parameter not working

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I downloaded the sample project file provided by Autodesk Forge to implement Design Automation from here: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/tree/nodejs

**Issue:** When I click 'Start WorkIttem' after filling in the desired width and height, the result in the log as posted below says 'success' but when I download the Revit file, the width and height of the geometry has not changed.

```
Defining appbundle and activity for Autodesk.Revit+2021
AppBundle: n1v10yCxcSRsqUwNKZWBXfCnCmlW9Gc5.UpdateRVTParamAppBundle+dev, v1
Activity: n1v10yCxcSRsqUwNKZWBXfCnCmlW9Gc5.UpdateRVTParamActivity+dev
Uploading input file...
Workitem started: d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8
{
  "status": "success",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/n1v10yCxcSRsqUwNKZWBXfCnCmlW9Gc5/d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=48600&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECcaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIGGKK6fJSyDUiMSfdIADqK07JJNWaD2s%2Bm1F3DWGFTHkAiAZtIXv9VKKrplyeUihf4NxD3ZplTqAr8MY5xmKH7eoFCqkAgiA%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAMaDDIyMDQ3MzE1MjMxMCIM%2BUhpeL5FbICg3wu4KvgBlqwOGqMfHI%2FgxrvPAojOWriGJNm7J15%2BJHaLOqOTo8OE9P1G4i0bSTDbe%2FWo7H74%2BNrVkQwpOdB3bimzchZfsyfJ0IPoLZH8VOioVBZ8N5cONX1OaG%2FjmBClRcjf1Y585fPm6ZDMQegqSD%2F2J7d4nw0I89UCgGyEChUFeeaqqcmaaUGvHt2fGdLt4P2gxlN%2FpQC2nUvBOyzp%2Bf5WaJzW3kw2LZNpAm%2BXSLzP1nD9RbyBQaZ2%2B99q15YBEDfDp6rGFdg9fIbR7xe8Zc0OgRt3AfSsmx8LLcw2WLM7NfR8aKO8fPiKTUR8n6gmy2TqCywW4p45uEujBf8wn%2BzakAY6mwGDCbARJYr8O0F7Ao4SB647IJHyFRQkujiqYXaIBk5DJ62tDQueyZYSpHzq5wMz4kuDISaDl9SseLI%2FAZYomipHLfhqTvc6SCu2wicYnl1nQw1rqbofUnHvN9F4M68w80N9%2FsSraF0nYx3JONWnDgm4xSMRGbs1ea8UvDYBTdbGYhPJDrFbMVlfZ7MWG1BZqWSc14SJDb1aEZcMcQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3MQKEMNHT/20220223/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220223T224950Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=2f202d8d664e27890e12cd33b84c1cde50159b5a5bb85c49085eb3d12ad6f1d5",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2022-02-23T22:49:50.2309588Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2022-02-23T22:49:50.546431Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2022-02-23T22:49:51.0632558Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2022-02-23T22:50:17.0379761Z",
    "timeUploadEnded": "2022-02-23T22:50:17.4759889Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 5468187,
    "bytesUploaded": 5468160
  },
  "id": "d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8"
}
Download result file here
[02/23/2022 22:49:50] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "$(engine.path)\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[inputFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[UpdateRVTParamAppBundle].path)\""
]
"Settings":{
  "script": {
    "value": ""
  },
  "dasreportfaileduploadoptional": {
    "value": "true",
    "isEnvironmentVariable": true
  }
}
"Id":"d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8"
"ActivityId":"n1v10yCxcSRsqUwNKZWBXfCnCmlW9Gc5.UpdateRVTParamActivity+dev"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.Revit_2021!75"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"n1v10yCxcSRsqUwNKZWBXfCnCmlW9Gc5.UpdateRVTParamAppBundle!1"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "inputFile": {
    "localName": "$(inputFile)",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:QoIYMQzQE828nGGjRkZ0geg1t1I=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:qujiT7I59fl3WJXQSr0Ey08rOl8="
    }
  },
  "inputJson": {
    "localName": "params.json",
    "url": "data:application/json, {'width':200,'height':200}"
  },
  "outputFile": {
    "localName": "outputFile.rvt",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:NmbWKyNOy7Nr9iWqM0XI5hbA4Ng=",
    "headers": {
      "Masked:XiXOAHqpXqLqixWK7pxjCjLqVhY=": "",
      "Content-type": "application/octet-stream"
    },
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "onComplete": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "optional": true,
    "url": "http://7693-38-106-54-98.ngrok.io/Masked:wbVB1+KYKIFwu+C5aH0Kv9t4/Ow=",
    "verb": "post"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "url": "https://wlnr5sjl3a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Masked:UK/Z3b5X3xUWxXiH6C9r9i9UlRU=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-das-authorize": "awssigv4(us-east-1)",
      "x-ads-token-data": "{\"access_token\":{\"client_id\":\"n1v10yCxcSRsqUwNKZWBXfCnCmlW9Gc5\"},\"scope\":\"bucket:create bucket:read bucket:delete data:read data:create data:write code:all\",\"expires_in\":3560,\"client_id\":\"n1v10yCxcSRsqUwNKZWBXfCnCmlW9Gc5\"}",
      "x-ads-gateway-secret": "Masked:F6VCvje5cIP0zOGCxgARjmSopQI="
    },
    "verb": "put"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 10800,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 5000
}
[02/23/2022 22:49:50] Starting work item d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8
[02/23/2022 22:49:50] Start download phase.
[02/23/2022 22:49:50] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/n1v10ycxcsrsquwnkzwbxfcncmlw9gc5-designautomation/objects/20220223224944_input_revit_sample_file.rvt'
[02/23/2022 22:49:50] Embedded resource [ {'width':200,'height':200}] is saved as file: T:\Aces\Jobs\d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8\params.json.
[02/23/2022 22:49:50] '5468160' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8\20220223224944_input_revit_sample_file.rvt.
[02/23/2022 22:49:50] End downloading file from 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/n1v10ycxcsrsquwnkzwbxfcncmlw9gc5-designautomation/objects/20220223224944_input_revit_sample_file.rvt'.
[02/23/2022 22:49:50] End download phase successfully.
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] Command line: [ /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8\20220223224944_input_revit_sample_file.rvt" /al "T:\Aces\Applications\d2772ec8e9675d0e224f76e126d353a4.n1v10yCxcSRsqUwNKZWBXfCnCmlW9Gc5.UpdateRVTParamAppBundle[1].package"]
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] Start script phase.
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] Start Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] Running in unattended mode.
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] ====== Revit is running: revitcoreconsole ======
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] Current Exe path: T:\Aces\AcesRoot\21.0\coreEngine\Exe\revitcoreconsole.exe
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] Echoing command line args:
[02/23/2022 22:49:51]   0:/i
[02/23/2022 22:49:51]   1:T:\Aces\Jobs\d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8\20220223224944_input_revit_sample_file.rvt
[02/23/2022 22:49:51]   2:/al
[02/23/2022 22:49:51]   3:T:\Aces\Applications\d2772ec8e9675d0e224f76e126d353a4.n1v10yCxcSRsqUwNKZWBXfCnCmlW9Gc5.UpdateRVTParamAppBundle[1].package
[02/23/2022 22:49:51]   4:/isolate
[02/23/2022 22:49:51]   5:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8
[02/23/2022 22:49:51]   6:T:\Aces\Jobs\d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8\userdata
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] Running RevitAssemblyResolver....
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] Initializing RevitCoreEngine...
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] Selected Revit\RCE install Path: (from app.config) C:\Revit2021
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] Resolving location of Revit/RevitCoreEngine installation...
[02/23/2022 22:49:51] Running user application....
[02/23/2022 22:49:55] Found an addIn for registration: Autodesk.Forge.Sample.DesignAutomation.Revit.addin
[02/23/2022 22:49:55] Initializing RCE....
[02/23/2022 22:49:55] Initializing RevitCoreEngine (and possibly running stub installer)...
[02/23/2022 22:49:55] Language not specified, using English-United States(ENU) as default.
[02/23/2022 22:49:58] Initialize and  get RCE: (VersionBuild) 21.1.60.25 (VersionNumber) 2021 (SubVersionNumber) 2021.2
[02/23/2022 22:50:04] Design Automation Ready event triggered...
[02/23/2022 22:50:07] Saving file...
[02/23/2022 22:50:15] Finished running.  Process will return: Success
[02/23/2022 22:50:15] ====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
[02/23/2022 22:50:16] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[02/23/2022 22:50:16] End script phase.
[02/23/2022 22:50:17] Start upload phase.
[02/23/2022 22:50:17] Uploading 'T:\Aces\Jobs\d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8\outputFile.rvt': verb - 'PUT', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/dc0f44a0-a50f-491e-80ff-c2605bd9dc6f?region=US'
[02/23/2022 22:50:17] End upload phase successfully.
[02/23/2022 22:50:17] Job finished with result Succeeded
[02/23/2022 22:50:17] Job Status:
{
  "status": "success",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/n1v10yCxcSRsqUwNKZWBXfCnCmlW9Gc5/d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=48600&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECcaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIGGKK6fJSyDUiMSfdIADqK07JJNWaD2s%2Bm1F3DWGFTHkAiAZtIXv9VKKrplyeUihf4NxD3ZplTqAr8MY5xmKH7eoFCqkAgiA%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAMaDDIyMDQ3MzE1MjMxMCIM%2BUhpeL5FbICg3wu4KvgBlqwOGqMfHI%2FgxrvPAojOWriGJNm7J15%2BJHaLOqOTo8OE9P1G4i0bSTDbe%2FWo7H74%2BNrVkQwpOdB3bimzchZfsyfJ0IPoLZH8VOioVBZ8N5cONX1OaG%2FjmBClRcjf1Y585fPm6ZDMQegqSD%2F2J7d4nw0I89UCgGyEChUFeeaqqcmaaUGvHt2fGdLt4P2gxlN%2FpQC2nUvBOyzp%2Bf5WaJzW3kw2LZNpAm%2BXSLzP1nD9RbyBQaZ2%2B99q15YBEDfDp6rGFdg9fIbR7xe8Zc0OgRt3AfSsmx8LLcw2WLM7NfR8aKO8fPiKTUR8n6gmy2TqCywW4p45uEujBf8wn%2BzakAY6mwGDCbARJYr8O0F7Ao4SB647IJHyFRQkujiqYXaIBk5DJ62tDQueyZYSpHzq5wMz4kuDISaDl9SseLI%2FAZYomipHLfhqTvc6SCu2wicYnl1nQw1rqbofUnHvN9F4M68w80N9%2FsSraF0nYx3JONWnDgm4xSMRGbs1ea8UvDYBTdbGYhPJDrFbMVlfZ7MWG1BZqWSc14SJDb1aEZcMcQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3MQKEMNHT/20220223/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220223T224950Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=2f202d8d664e27890e12cd33b84c1cde50159b5a5bb85c49085eb3d12ad6f1d5",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2022-02-23T22:49:50.2309588Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2022-02-23T22:49:50.546431Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2022-02-23T22:49:51.0632558Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2022-02-23T22:50:17.0379761Z",
    "timeUploadEnded": "2022-02-23T22:50:17.4759889Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 5468187,
    "bytesUploaded": 5468160
  },
  "id": "d1a1b5ee070f47cf9bb2cc12f7556eb8"
}
```

**Can someone help me with this issue? I'm new with Autodesk Forge and WebAPI, so I'm not able to figure out why this is failing although it says the result is a success. Thanks.**

Note: Based on the link below, I did try the 'Clear Account' to clear the App bundles & the activities and tried setting it again but no luck. https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/rundebug/2legged_da

Comment: some questions: when you test, did you change any codes of the sample, or the plugin code? did you test with your own model or the sample model ? If you still have the issue, please try to check availability of  any of my team colleagues at https://calendly.com/autodeskforge. Many of us are familiar with this sample. We could diagnose remotely. Be careful with the time zone.

Comment: I performed the test with the sample today. I downloaded it again from source and setup the running. I tried to change the width, height to some values. It looks all work well, the result size of the object are changed.  This is the test video: https://myshare.autodesk.com/:v:/g/personal/xiaodong_liang_autodesk_com/EduZiHtv4TJEurExaVKt1MAB6lAzTXuBDrDA_6rVfXbSzg?e=Yo1Axl .  I deleted previous files and downloaded the output file by VSCode extension, while I also performed more tests that downloaded by the built-in functionality of the sample